# Ubuntu 12.04 нету mysql-gui-tools-common

Tags: ubuntu

Не могу установить mysql-gui-tools-common из репозитория. Такое ощущение что его выпилили из дистрибутива или репозиторий с ним отвалился. Подскажите как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/mysql-gui-tools-common